# Rails: How to disallow access to new, delete, edit URL for a resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know Rails generate new, delete, and edit, and whatever the other is for all resources. So if you have a model user, you can go to /user/1, etc. But I want all of these auto-generated urls to be disallowed access? How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your config/routes.rb file by removing `map.resources :users` and just add the route that you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can restrict the routes when you say [`resources :users`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created):

```
resources :users, :only => [ :index, :show ]
```